# Java code to create SAML 2.0 AuthnRequest based on meta data xmls

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, service-provider

Can someone please share the complete Java code to create an AuthnRequest for web browser sso based SAML2.0. We have a service provider to use a 3rd party IDP. I am working with a J2EE component in the DMZ that wouldn't let any jar files to add, so I am looking at writing complete Java code to produce an AuthnRequest and redirect the user to the IDP.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you cant include any jar you'll have to generate the XML your self, do you atleast have som XML lib?

Comment: Sorry just what come with JRE 6

Answer (score 0):

I strongly doubt there is any implementation out there that does this without any external dependecies.

I suggest you look into the implementation of [simplesamlphp](http://simplesamlphp.org/). The code is quite easy to understand but to implement this correclty and securly at your end I would recommend that you have a good understanding of the SAML 2.0 protocol

I would advice aginst this as there is a big risk of introducing security issues. This will take time and should be thoroughly tested